# Parsed XML to Listbox

Tags: c#, xml, listbox

I've already did a similar thing with this simple code:

```
 var data = from query in xml.Descendants("item")
                   select new Object
                   {
                       Element = (string)query.Element("element"),
                   };
        listBox.ItemsSource = data;
```

But I had to deal also with a nested XML so I was worried that the code wouldn't have worked with that file, so I followed this topic [Deserializing nested xml into C# objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14783406/deserializing-nested-xml-into-c-sharp-objects) and now I don't know how to show the datas in a listbox.

I use this class to serialize the XML:

```
{
[XmlRoot("contacts")]

public class Contacts
{
    [XmlElement("building")]
    public Building[] BuildingList { get; set; }

}

public class Building
{
    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("address")]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("tel")]
    public string Tel { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("link")]
    public string Link { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("timing")]
    public string Timing { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("contacts"), XmlArrayItem("contact")]
    public Contact[] ContactList { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("contact")]
public class Contact
{
    [XmlElement("surname")]
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("area")]
    public string Area { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("role")]
    public string Role { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("tel")]
    public string Tel { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("email")]
    public string email { get; set; }
}
```

This is my listbox:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox_buildings">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top">
                            <TextBlock  x:Name="text_title" Foreground="Black" FontSize="25"  TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Anybody has some clues? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without knowing how did you implement solution proposed in the linked question. Assuming you have a `Users` class to map the XML as suggested there :

```
public class Users
{
    [XmlElement("user")]
    public User[] UserList { get; set; }
}
```

You can show the data in `ListBox` this way for example :

```
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Users));
var u = (Users)ser.Deserialize(stream);
listBox.ItemsSource = u.UserList;
```

**UPDATE :**

According to new information you posted, you can try this :

```
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Contacts));
var u = (Contacts)ser.Deserialize(stream);
listBox_buildings.ItemsSource = u.BuildingList;
```

Comment: Mm the compiler gives me: "'System.Windows.Controls.ListBox' does not contain a definition for 'ItemSource' and no extension method 'ItemSource' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.ListBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" I'm adding new informations to my original post

Comment: I've tried the exact same thing but it gives me the error that I have written above