# Deserializing XML into object returns null values

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, deserialization

I am trying to deserialize an XML document but the code I using is returning Null Value each time.

I have a XML like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RegistrationOpenData xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://example.gov">
<Description>Registration data is collected by ABC XYZ</Description>
<InformationURL>http://www.example.com/html/hpd/property-reg-unit.shtml</InformationURL>
<SourceAgency>ABC Department of Housing</SourceAgency>
<SourceSystem>PREMISYS</SourceSystem>
<StartDate>2016-02-29T00:03:06.642772-05:00</StartDate>
<EndDate i:nil="true" />
<Registrations>
<Registration xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<RegistrationID>108260</RegistrationID>
<BuildingID>4731</BuildingID>
</Registration>
</Registrations>
</RegistrationOpenData>
```

to deserialize it, I have created a class

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Xml;
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://example.gov")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="http://example.gov", IsNullable=true)]
public partial class Registration : InfoClass {

  private long registrationIDField;
  private bool registrationIDFieldSpecified;
  private System.Nullable<long> buildingIDField;
  private bool buildingIDFieldSpecified;

  public long RegistrationID
 {
    get
    {
        return this.registrationIDField;
    }
    set
    {
        this.registrationIDField = value;
    }
}
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
public bool RegistrationIDSpecified {
    get {
        return this.registrationIDFieldSpecified;
    }
    set {
        this.registrationIDFieldSpecified = value;
    }
}

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
public System.Nullable<long> BuildingID {
    get {
        return this.buildingIDField;
    }
    set {
        this.buildingIDField = value;
    }
}

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
public bool BuildingIDSpecified {
    get {
        return this.buildingIDFieldSpecified;
    }
    set {
        this.buildingIDFieldSpecified = value;
    }
}
```

and the code I am using is

```
public void Test()
    {

        Registration RegistrationVal = null;
        var xRoot = new XmlRootAttribute();
        xRoot.ElementName = "RegistrationOpenData";
        xRoot.Namespace = "http://services.hpd.gov";
        xRoot.IsNullable = true;
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Registration), xRoot);
        using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(@"D:\sample.xml"))
            {
                RegistrationVal = (Registration)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            }
}
```

Here it is always returning Null value.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Does any exception appear when you debug?

Comment: No, I tried to get value of RegistrationID in TextBox and it prints 0

Comment: What code is in your `InfoClass`? are there any xml attributes?

Comment: No there are XMLElements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in the xml because it has a list of registrations. If you remove `<Registration>` and `<Registrations>` tag then it works. Do you need the `Registration` and `Registrations` because in this case you have to work with `Lists`.

You could do it like in this example ([Deserializing nested xml into C# objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14783406/deserializing-nested-xml-into-c-sharp-objects))

And create a own class `Registrations` which hold a `List` of `Registration` Elements.

With this code it works. Create a super class:

```
[XmlRoot("RegistrationOpenData")]
public class RegistrationOpenData
{
    [XmlElement("Registrations")]
    public Registrations Regs { get; set; }
}
```

and the `Registrations`:

```
[XmlRoot("Registrations")]
public class Registrations
{
    [XmlElement("Registration")]
    public List<Registration> Regs { get; set; }
}
```

and the `Registration` should be the same as before. 
The main function should change to this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        RegistrationOpenData RegistrationVal = null;
        var xRoot = new XmlRootAttribute();
        xRoot.ElementName = "RegistrationOpenData";
        xRoot.Namespace = "http://services.hpd.gov";
        xRoot.IsNullable = true;
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RegistrationOpenData), xRoot);
        using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(@"D:\sample.xml"))
        {
            RegistrationVal = (RegistrationOpenData)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
}
```

Comment: I cannot remove those tags manually, shall I remove those through code?

Comment: You can do it like i described in the answer by using a `Registrations` class or like you mentioned removing this tags.

Comment: Thanks for your help Kevin, I feel your solution will work, I will apply this in a while. Right now StreamReader not returning any value. I am tired of using XMLTextReader and StreamReader, actually the file I am parsing is 560MB and that is also a big problem now

Comment: @Hanumendra i tried the above code and it worked on my computer. You can close this question and when the problem with the `StreamReader` does not dissapear you can open a new question :)

Comment: just marked your answer :) Really thanks for your help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114423/discussion-between-hanumendra-and-kevin-wallis).