# XML returns NULL on XmlSerializer Deserialize DotNet Core C# (Console App)

Tags: c#, xml, .net-core

I know this question is not new, but after searching for quite while, I decided to ask for help here.
My XML deserialization is always null and I would like your thoughts on my code.

```
private static bool MyJson(string mxl)
{
   XmlRootAttribute xRoot = new XmlRootAttribute();
                xRoot.ElementName = "Client";
                xRoot.IsNullable = true;
                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyDTO), xRoot);
                MyDTO result;
                using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(xml))
                {
                   result = serializer.Deserialize(reader) as MyDTO;
                }
...
}
```

My XML

```
<Client>
    <References>
        <Reference>TE01234</Reference>
    </References>
    <Intro>
        <Name>Test</Name>
    </Intro>
    <Details>
        <Claimant>
            <Title>Mr</Title>
            <FirstName>Cxxx</FirstName>
            <Surname>Msyy</Surname>
        </Claimant>
        <Claimant2>
            <Title2>Mrs</Title2>
            <FirstName2>Xmsxx</FirstName2>
            <Surname2>Cktol</Surname2>
        </Claimant2>
    </Details>
</Client>
```

My Model

```
public class MyDTO
{
   public string Reference {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public string Title {get;set;}
   public string FirstName {get;set;}
   public string Surname {get;set;}
   public string Title2 {get;set;}
   public string FirstName2 {get;set;}
   public string Surname2 {get;set;}
}
```

The 'result; is always null.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: your DTO model doesn't seem to match your XML schema. For instance, you have some "lists" (pluralized tags) containing one (or maybe more) singular tags. You could have a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14783406/deserializing-nested-xml-into-c-sharp-objects for instance, or try to look for simple examples "with nested tags", there are lots of them.

Comment: also the example C# code you showed does not compile, you are missing some types for some of your properties

Comment: your XML is also invalid. A tag `<Claimant>` seems to be "closed" by `</primaryClaimant>`

Answer (score 0):

Use xml Linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            List<MyDTO> dtos = doc.Descendants("Client").Select(x => new MyDTO()
            {
                Reference = (string)x.Descendants("Reference").FirstOrDefault(),
                Name = (string)x.Descendants("Name").FirstOrDefault(),
                Title = (string)x.Descendants("Title").FirstOrDefault(),
                FirstName = (string)x.Descendants("FirstName").FirstOrDefault(),
                Surname = (string)x.Descendants("Surname").FirstOrDefault(),
                Title2 = (string)x.Descendants("Title2").FirstOrDefault(),
                FirstName2 = (string)x.Descendants("FirstName2").FirstOrDefault(),
                Surname2 = (string)x.Descendants("Surname2").FirstOrDefault()
            }).ToList();

        }
    }
    public class MyDTO
    {
       public string Reference {get;set;}
       public string Name {get;set;}
       public string Title {get;set;}
       public string FirstName {get;set;}
       public string Surname {get;set;}
       public string Title2 {get;set;}
       public string FirstName2 {get;set;}
       public string Surname2 {get;set;}
    }


}
```